# Odoo 10 - Button on tree view clickable before creating the record

Tags: listview, button, odoo

I'm using Odoo 10.
I'm trying to make a button, inside a *many2one* tree inside a form view, clickable as soon as a line is initialized.

The problem is that the *id* of the row, client side, is of type *'one2many_v_id_xxx'* until I save the record. So the *ListView* widget sets the button as *disabled* while creating the record.
Result: I can click the button only after the record has been created.

I've read some posts about create the line inside an *onchange* method, but I've got dependencies about the model linked to the *form view*, so I can't create the line before the actual record creation.

Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks in advance.

---

Py:

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('product_template_id')
def product_template_id_change(self):

    < some operations >

    self.create(vals) # It gives me a validation error about 'order_id', a many2one relation with the model linked to the form view

    self.update(vals)
```

View:

```
<button type="object" name="open_grid_wizard"
        string="Open product variant grid"
        icon="fa-table"
        class="oe_stat_button"/>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am facing this right now and can't seem to find a way to deal with it...